# Warning: Ignoring excess mask dialog entries in:

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm having serious trouble debugging the following Matlab Warning:

Warning: Ignoring excess mask dialog entries in:

(path to block under mask of block of Simulink model I'm running)

Does anybody know what it even means? What are "mask dialog entries"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the block saved in your .mdl file has too many parameters saved in the MaskValueString parameter.  This shouldn't happen during normal use, but it can happen if you directly do a set_param the MaskValueString parameter on the masked block instead of using the dialog, and you end up setting more values than there are parameters.  Simulink will just ignore all of the extra parameters in this case.

I think if you resave the model that the masked block lives in, the warning should go away.  Just make sure your block has the right parameter values on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but I suspect that it means that you've got too many attributes defined in your block mask?

Is the mask particularly complex?

You could examine the mask definition by right clicking on the block and selecting "edit mask" - which will bring up the mask editor, and allow you to examine what attributes of the block are being defined via its mask.

Or I could be completely wrong....